# python variable referenced before assignment int vs array

Tags: python, scope

When I compile this snippet with func1 I get an error about referencing output before assignment, which seems reasonable to me:

```
def func1():
    output += 1

output = 0
func1()
print(output)
```

But when I compile this snippet with func2 I don't get an error, which seems unreasonable to me.

```
def func2():
    output.append(1)

output = []
func2()
print(output)
```

Thoughts? Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a duplicate. I didn't didn't see this particular question addressed in similarly titled posts when researching.

Comment: Try to make the variable output global. Otherwise, the function cannot access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in how Python binds *names* to *variables*.

Any time you write an assignment in a function (something like `a = b` or `a += b`), Python will bind that name **locally** for the **entire** function scope.  This means that any variables with that name declared outside the function are **ignored**.

For example:

```
a = 1 # This variable is ignored.
def foo():
    print(a) # "a" hasn't been defined yet!
    a = 2 # This causes "a" to bind to a local variable.
```

This will produce an `UnboundLocalError` at the print statement because Python sees that `a` is assigned to later in the function, and binds it locally, ignoring the variable you defined outside the function.  Since `a` is only defined *after* the print statement, you get an error.

This can be very confusing because removing the `a += 2` line will cause the print statement to work as expected!

The solution is to explicitly tell Python **not** to bind the name locally.  This can be done with the `global` and `nonlocal` keywords, e.g.:

```
a = 1
def foo():
    nonlocal a # or: global a
    print(a)
    a += 2
```

`global` tells Python to bind the name in the module's global scope, while `nonlocal` (introduced in Python 3) tells Python to bind to the **enclosing** scope (for example, if you define a function inside a function).

There's a nice explanation of this (with examples) in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) :-)

---

Once we understand these rules, we can see that your first example fails because you're trying to increment a variable that doesn't yet exist.  `output += 1` is equivalent to `output = output + 1`, which triggers local name binding.

On the other hand, your second example doesn't trigger the error because you're not assigning to `output` (you're *mutating* it instead), so it will bind to the global variable that you defined.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, global variables when called in functions don't work all the same.

The data types (on a high level) in Python can be categorised into "mutable" and "immutable".

- If you have have mutable datatypes like `list` then they can be both : accessed **and** modified in the function without referring them with a `global` keyword.

Eg:

```
l = []
def foo():
    l.append(1) #works

foo()
print(l) # prints [1], so foo() changed the global list l.
```

- But if you have immutable types like `int` or `str` then they can be accessed **but not** modified.

Eg:

```
someString = "abcdef"

def foo():
    print(someString[2]) # prints "c"
    someString += "l"    # error as someString cannot be modified unless you include it in the function foo() with the global keyword as shown below.
```

- But to modify a global variable of immutable types like `str` you have to include it first with the `global` keyword then you're free to use it like any local variable.

Eg:

```
someString = "abcdef"

def foo():
    global someString    # This now includes someString in foo() scope and is allowed to be modified.

    print(someString[2]) # prints "c"

    someString += "l"    # works as expected

    print(someString) # prints "abcdefl"
```

- Thanks to [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) for this valuable point.  At the end, you cannot reassign a global variable without the global keyword, irrespective of whether the variable is mutable or immutable.

Eg:

```
someInt  = 1
someStr  = "abc"
someList = [1,2,3]

def foo():
    someInt  += 3     # error, local variable referenced before assignment.
    someStr  += "def" # error, local variable referenced before assignment.
    someList += [4]   # error,  local variable referenced before assignment. Note that this is **not** the same as doing someList.append(4).
```

To make the above work, include them in the function via `global` keyword and use them as required.

Comment: Terminology nitpick...you can't *modify* an immutable variable.  You can't *reassign* a name in the global namespace in a local function without the global keyword, regardless if it is mutable or immutable.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you for pointing that out. Added the changes in the edit.

Comment: I'm afraid this has nothing to do with mutability/immutability.  The problem is really about how Python binds names in function scope.